# Command CompileSwiftSources failed + Segmentation fault: 11 when trying to archive iOS part of Flutter project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter, dart

I am trying to use 2 packages that reached iOS native SDKs in my Flutter app.

I've installed both packages, and it all works perfectly fine when I run it using `flutter build iOS`, but for some reason when I try to archive the project for release using Xcode, I get the following message from the native SDKs:

**StripeCore SDK**:

```
remark: Incremental compilation has been disabled: it is not compatible with whole module optimization
Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code
```

**twilio_voice SDK**:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I've tried:

1. Running `pod install --repo-update`
2. Deleting `Podfile.lock`
3. Deleting Xcode derived data

but none of these worked.

Here is my `Podfile`:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '13.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

I am not sure it is related, but I am running it on Macbook Pro with an M1 processor.

[image: Screenshot]

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: Any solution ? I have same issue

Comment: @samirasalah I have ended up disabling the bitcode. Not the optimal solution, but it's fine until they will fix it

Comment: @F.SO7 how to disable bitcode? I'm having same issue but with Twilio Programmable Video.

Comment: @Jches It is in Xcode build settings